# I did git branch some-remote-branch by mistake

Tags: git, github

I wanted to change branch to an existing remote branch, but by mistake I did `git branch some-remote-branch` which creates a new local branch.

How to can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the new local branch and then checkout to the correct remote branch.

```
git branch --delete some-remote-branch
git fetch (if your repo doesn't have the remote branch already)
git checkout -t origin/correct-branch
```

Comment: I did have to first go to another branch (or master) to be able to delete. But otherwise worked great :)

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing to fix there. Just

```
git checkout correct-branch
```

This will create a local branch named `correct-branch` same as `origin/correct-branch` and you will be switched into that.

No need to delete the branch `some-other-branch` you created locally.

Comment: This is what I did first, but that did not help. Grinch91 answer worked great (if I first checked out another branch).

Comment: @EricC if your local repo was up to date, this should work. Possibly that should be the problem. so 'git fetch' will do that. Anyway nice to see you have solved your problem. :))